# Pass parameters in header using curl

Tags: php, web-services, curl

I have params like

```
$A='ZAXGHGN';
$INPUT='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><a><b>test data</b></a>';
$array= array('A:'.$A,'INPUT:'.$INPUT);
```

Below is my curl code

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$array );

    $data = curl_exec($ch); 
    if(curl_errno($ch))
    print curl_error($ch);
    else
    curl_close($ch);
     echo "<pre>"; print_r($data);exit;
```

When i try to execute the code i am getting below error.

**Output :**

Bad Request - Invalid Header
HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.

Comment: Does the request work without `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$array );`?

Comment: Your code is working here. What are your PHP and cURL versions?

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
$A = 'ZAXGHGN';
$INPUT = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><a><b>test data</b></a>'; // is this a valid XML???

$headers = array(
    "Content-type: text/xml",
    "Content-length: " . strlen($INPUT),
    "A: " . $A,
    // like this  if you want to have this value  in the header ... but to put the xml inside the header info...
    "Connection: close"
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $INPUT); // send xml data using POST 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch))
    print curl_error($ch);
else
    curl_close($ch);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
exit;
```

Comment: I just saw that but xml $INPUT should be passed with parameter name 'INPUT'

Comment: same data when i pass $A, $INPUT as header params  using restclient i am getting response. But when i hit the curl with params as mentioned above(by coding) i am not getting response.

Comment: You have 2 variables .. $A and $INPUT. $A can be sent as part of the header information but the content of the $INPUT variable I don't think it can be part of the header in this format(XML).